# MVC: In which component do details of data presentation specified?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, oop

Example is fake.

ASP.NET MVC: I have a view that renders a student info. Student info consists of First Name, Last Name and (optional) Age (declared as `int?`).

Student info is rendered something like, if age is not specified I want to show "not specified":

```
<span><%= Model.Student.FirstName %></span>
<span><%= Model.Student.LastName %></span>
<span><%= Model.Student.Age.HasValue ? Model.Student.Age.ToString() : "not specified" %></span>
```

My problem with text above is that it makes view too complicated (too complicated for my web designer to be able to modify it).

**Question:** Where could I move that decision?

1. Property `Student` of model is a business object, and shall not contain details of rendering.
2. Should I add a method to Model: `Model.GetAgeAsText(Student student)`? But then I end up with a host of loosely hanging methods on Model, that are crying to be grouped into something...but what?
3. I could create a custom control `StudentAgeShower`, this appears to be the most OO-correct solution, but seems to be bit overkill.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a View Model of a Student with all the decisions premade.

Comment: I like, i like. And then expose `StudentViewModel` as a property of the `Model`? At what point is that `StudentViewModel` is created? and where does it live?

Comment: yes,  but I would still call it "Student",  the view model is created anywhere before its used.... usually if I'm decorating like that I go  View(new ViewModel(realModel))  kind of thing  (might be more involved)    there are things like http://automapper.codeplex.com/  and the like to help some of these things,  depends how often you need to do this, and how complex your objects are

Comment: No, generally not, I'd generally use a formatting function in the view for dates and times.